# Replacing value in an XML file with ANT

Tags: xml, ant, replace

How to replace a specific occurrence of

```
<xsd:element name="details" type="tns:taskMetadata"/>
```

with

```
<xsd:element name="details" type="tns:task"/>
```

in an xml file, There are multiple occurrences of same.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use third party library, consider [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/). It is listed in external task list at [apache-ant site](http://ant.apache.org/external.html).

If the requirement is small (like in my code), you may write small java program and call it from [ant-javatask](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XSLT task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) to accomplish this without having to use a third party task.
Though the xmltask @Jayan mentions doesn't require much xslt knowledge.

Someone is going to tell you to use the replace task... don't listen to them.
Read [my favorite SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/505191) of all time for more info